# How to display a particular value based on conditional logic applied to rows with a shared value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

**Desired Behaviour**

Display a particular value based on conditional logic applied to rows with a shared value.

**What I've tried**

I'm a full stack developer (MongoDB/Node/JS) and not used to solving data problems in Excel.

I'm therefore not sure of the constructs that are available to solve this particular problem (e.g arrays, variables, loops etc).

(Or even if something of this complexity is possible in Excel).

However, this is what I would like to achieve - where the `IMPORT or DELETE` column values are calculated based on logic defined below.

| Employee Number | Course Code | Completion Date | IMPORT or DELETE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111 | AAAA | 01/05/2021 | IMPORT |
| 11111111 |  | 01/10/2020 |  |
| 22222222 |  | 01/11/2021 |  |
| 22222222 | AAAA | 01/10/2021 | DELETE |
| 22222222 | AAAA | 01/10/2015 | DELETE |
| 33333333 | AAAA | 30/01/2021 | IMPORT |
| 33333333 | AAAA | 30/01/2020 | IMPORT |
| 33333333 |  | 30/01/2000 |  |
| 44444444 | AAAA | 01/01/2022 | IMPORT |
| 55555555 | AAAA | 01/01/2021 | IMPORT |
| 55555555 | AAAA | 01/01/2020 | IMPORT |
| 66666666 | AAAA | 01/01/2019 | DELETE |

```
Reason for IMPORT or DELETE value: 

1] 11111111 - IMPORT - because it is newer than existing record and after 01/01/2020
2] 22222222 - DELETE - because it is older than existing record
3] 22222222 - DELETE - because it is older than existing record
4] 33333333 - IMPORT - because it is newer than existing record and after 01/01/2020
5] 33333333 - IMPORT - because it is newer than existing record and after 01/01/2020
6] 44444444 - IMPORT - because there is no existing record and it is after 01/01/2020
7] 55555555 - IMPORT - because there is no existing record and it is after 01/01/2020
8] 55555555 - IMPORT - because there is no existing record and it is after 01/01/2020
9] 66666666 - DELETE - because there is no existing record but it is before 01/01/2020
```

**Spreadsheet Information**

The spreadsheet data is custom sorted by:

- Employee Number (Smallest to Largest)
- Completion Date (Newest to Oldest)

The records that do not have a `Course Code` value are existing records.

The records that do have a `Course Code` value are new records.

'Duplicate' records are considered to be those with the same `Employee Number`.

There are intentionally various scenarios covered in the above data set.

The data set size can be significant, eg ~1,000 rows.

Date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

**Pseudo Code**

The goal is to display `IMPORT` or `DELETE` for the new records.

Below is a guess at some pseudo code.

You may wish to ignore this approach as it might be going in the wrong direction.

`01`  'Group' each set of duplicates (or individual user record), eg:

```
[ [11111111], [22222222], [33333333], [44444444], [55555555], [66666666] ]
```

`02`  Identify if one of the records in the 'employee number group' is an existing record

`03`  IF one of the values in a group is an existing record, display 'IMPORT' for new records that are newer than the existing record and 01/01/2020, and 'DELETE' for the rest.

`04`  ELSE IF none of the values in a group are existing records, display 'IMPORT' for new records that are newer than 01/01/2020, and 'DELETE' for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be implementing this behaviour as a Macro in Visual Basic. This provides a way of iterating over rows/columns to implement the wanted behaviour.
Macros can be written in View>Macros>Show Macros>Create

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).